# \hline spacing warning

Tags: rules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the \rule equivalent for \hrule?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17124/what-is-the-rule-equivalent-for-hrule)

How do I get spacing after a hline without an error? Here is what I currently have:

```
End of content\\[5pt]
\hline\\[5pt]
```

But this throws a coupe of errors:

```
hw.tex:XXX: There's no line here to end.
hw.tex:XXX: leading text:     \hline\\[5px]
```

This is related to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696157/latex-hline-spacing, but the answer there is the reason I'm getting errors.

Comment: See this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696157/latex-hline-spacing

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Notice that `\hline` can be used only inside `tabular`: are you trying to use it in running text?

Comment: Yes, is there a good and/or proper way to add a line to separate text content?