# What is the thickness of \hrulefill

Tags: rules

This seems like a simple question ...

I know from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17124/what-is-the-rule-equivalent-for-hrule) that `\hrule` and presumably `\hrulefill` have a thickness of 0.4pt. I think `\hrule` is a primitive, so does that mean that you cannot change the thickness of `\hrulefill`?

Comment: You can use `\hrule  height 4pt`. See TeXbook chapter 21 page 221.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The default height for `\hrule` is `0.4pt` (not a parameter whose default value is `0.4pt`) so you are correct that it may not be changed via setting a parameter. However `\hrulefill` is only a macro so you can change it if you wish.

It is defined by

```
\def\hrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule\hfill\kern\z@}
```

so

```
\def\hrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 2pt\hfill\kern\z@}
```

would make it thicker

Comment: I am assuming it is not possible to define a primitive that depends on a parameter, since that doesn't seem like it would be a primitive anymore.

Comment: Well yes you or I can't define a primitive however it would have been possible for tex-the-program to define the default widths of rules to be a dimen register `\defaultrulewidth` or some such, but it doesn't. Compare with the primitive `\indent` which indents by an amount given by the primitive dimen parameter `\parindent`. Somewhat unusually in TeX, the rule width is a hard wired numerical default.

Comment: Perhaps instead of `\z@` we Plain TeX guys could use `0pt`? Searching on it brought me to [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55400/what-does-z-do) which suggests so.

Comment: @DanielLyons you could but \z@ is defined in plain as well (plain.tex line 258)

Comment: I see it there, but I get `Undefined control sequence` from xetex.

Comment: @DanielLyons of course you would in latex too: you need to make the definition at a point that `@` is a letter (`\catcode\`\@=11)` otherwise you have `\z` (undefined) followed by `@`

Comment: Sounds like a lot of work to save one character. :)

Comment: @DanielLyons It makes the code noticeably quicker to run, In 1980 it made the code **much** quicker to run.

Comment: I'm sorry to "extend the discussion" but how can that be true? `\z@` is just a 0pt dimension value... how can it be faster to use that than a 0pt literal? I believe you... I would just like to understand why.

Comment: @DanielLyons there is extensive discussion on that and explicit timings in my answer to the question that you referenced in my comment see also Knuth's comment on the line above in plain.tex

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks, and sorry I didn't see it earlier--it was right there!