# New line in a Nomenclature label conflicts with \nomgroup

Tags: spacing, nomenclature

Following the solution given in
[New line in a Nomenclature](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=11845)

I am using

```
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{\smash{\parbox[t]{1.5cm}{#1}}\hfil}
```

However, it conflicts with the `\nomgroup` (see below).

Code example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage[noprefix]{nomencl}

% Configure title of groups
\newcommand{\bfdz}[1]{\bf\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont #1}
\newcommand{\meru}[1]{\rule[2pt]{\textwidth-(\widthof{#1})}{.5pt}}

% Enable two line label
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{\smash{\parbox[t]{1.5cm}{#1}}\hfil}

% Create Groups
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{\vspace{5mm} \item[\bfdz General Symbols] \meru{\bfdz General Symbols~~}}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{\vspace{5mm} \item[\bfdz Greek Symbols] \meru{\bfdz Greek Symbols~~}}{}}}

\makenomenclature 

\begin{document}

\printnomenclature[1.5cm]

\nomenclature[A]{$p(r_m,t)$, $p_m(t)$}{Received signal at the $m^{th}$ microphone\nomrefpage}%{}{}

\nomenclature[G]{$\Delta t_{\vec{x}}$}{Emission time delay at focus point $\vec{x}$, $\Delta t_{\vec{x}}=r_{\vec{x}} / c$\nomrefpage}%{}{}

\end{document}
```

If you comment the line

```
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{{\parbox[t]{1.5cm}{#1}}\hfil}
```

you will get correct title, but wrong label size.

**Incorrect title**
[image: screenshot]

Does anyone know a way to fix it ?

Comment: Hi Will [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I added your image, and thanks for providing a MWE :) Welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On [www.latex-community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=22190) I made the following suggestion to the very same question:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[noprefix]{nomencl}

% define a command for the group heading:
% \rlap overlaps to the right => ``break out'' of the labels box
% and set a box over the whole textwidth;
% create the rule with \hrulefill rather than measuring the
% remaining space.
% let's also not use \bf but rather \bfseries (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5049)
% and use \large instead of explicitly chhoose the font size:
\newcommand\grouphead[1]{%
  \rlap{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{\textbf{\large#1 \hrulefill}}%
  }\hfill
}

% Enable two line label
% I added \RaggedRight from the `ragged2e' package here to avoid
% over- and underfull boxes
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{%
  \smash{\parbox[t]{.15\linewidth}{\RaggedRight#1}}}

% Create Groups
% the tests can be done without any additional package
% (they will fail, though, for a group like `aa')
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
  \ifx#1A\relax
    \item[\grouphead{General Symbols}]
  \fi
  \ifx#1G\relax
    \item[\grouphead{Greek Symbols}]
  \fi
  \bigskip}

\makenomenclature 

\begin{document}

Text bla bla

\printnomenclature[1.5cm]

\nomenclature[A]{$p(r_m,t)$, $p_m(t)$}{Received signal at the $m^{th}$
  microphone\nomrefpage}

\nomenclature[G]{$\Delta t_{\vec{x}}$}{Emission time delay at focus point
  $\vec{x}$, $\Delta t_{\vec{x}}=r_{\vec{x}} / c$\nomrefpage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that I chose `\bfseries` over `\bf` (see [Does it matter if I use \textit or \it, \bfseries or \bf, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5049) for reasons) and `\large` over `\fontsize{}{}\selectfont`.

For a thicker line one could follow David's answer on [What is the thickness of \hrulefill](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65731/what-is-the-thickness-of-hrulefill) and maybe define a corresponding `\nomgrouprulefill`.

Comment: Cgnieder, thanks a lot ! Since before I got no answer there I tried here !

Comment: @WillFonseca you're welcome!

Comment: note: I was getting an error until I changed `\smash{\parbox[t]{.15\linewidth}{\RaggedRight#1}}}` to `\smash{\parbox[t]{.15\linewidth}{\raggedright#1}}}` this might be an error with my setup, but might be of interest to others... SpB.

Comment: You forgot to load the `ragged2e` package as in cgneider's answer.  The `\RaggedRight` command much better than `\raggedright`.