# How can I change the thickness of \hrulefill

Tags: rules, exam

I am writing a worksheet for a math ed class. I am asking questions and would like the answer lines to start as soon as the question ends, and not the next line. This is partly because I want to start the answer (then students finish it) as well as there is limited space.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
  \begin{questions}
    \question List the names of 10 people in your class? Ben, Donna, \hrulefill\fillwithlines{0.5in}
  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the two sets of lines are different thicknesses.

Any ideas?

Comment: I found the answer here. I can change the thickness of the hrulefill line. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65731/what-is-the-thickness-of-hrulefill Thanks. Garth