# Thicker hrulefill in res class

Tags: resume, cv

How do I make a thicker horizontal line using hrulefill in res class? I have the following in my preamble. Is it possible to modify it in some way to reflect the change?

```
\newcommand{\fullhrulefill}
{
    \hspace*{-\sectionwidth}
    \hrulefill
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing from David's answer at [What is the thickness of \hrulefill](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65731/what-is-the-thickness-of-hrulefill), except here, I don't redefine `\hrulefill`, but rather replace its use inside of `\fullhrulefill`.

```
\documentclass{res}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fullhrulefill}
{%
    \def\xhrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 2pt\hfill\kern\z@}%
    \hspace*{-\sectionwidth}%
    \xhrulefill%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\fullhrulefill

\noindent\hrulefill
\end{document}
```

[image]