# Horizontal Rule Across page

Tags: errors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the \rule equivalent for \hrule?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17124/what-is-the-rule-equivalent-for-hrule)

I found this [online](http://timmurphy.org/2009/08/15/drawing-horizontal-lines-in-latex/) to produce a horizontal line across the page:

```
\begin{center}
    \line(1,0){250}
\end{center}
```

But I want it to stretch across the page with the width of the text. So I tried:

```
\begin{center}
    \line(2,0){\textwidth}
\end{center}
```

Although this displayed correctly it threw up a lot of errors that I'd like to remove. The errors were:

```
 ./Template.tex:28: Missing number, treated as zero.
 <to be read again> 
     \vrule 
 l.28 \line(2,0){\textwidth}                        
 ? 
 ./Template.tex:28: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
 <to be read again> 
     \vrule 
 l.28 \line(2,0){\textwidth}
```

So how else could I try to display the line with the width of the page?

Comment: Is the result of `\hrule` what you want?

Comment: @SašoŽivanović Yes. And found this [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17124/what-is-the-rule-equivalent-for-hrule) on how to change the thickness. I thought `\hrule` was only for tables.

Comment: See also this [related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17124/what-is-the-rule-equivalent-for-hrule)